# Enabling "navigation" mode in skobbler Android API

Tags: android, skmaps

I can't find a way to make my app, which currently implements SKmaps to the point of showing a route, show the route and follow the route like a car navigator.

example: [image]

This is my "route loading" method:

```
 @Override
public void onAllRoutesCompleted() {
    SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new SKNavigationSettings();
    navigationSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.REAL);
    navigationSettings.setNavigationMode(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationMode.CAR);
    navigationSettings.setCcpAsCurrentPosition(true);
    navigationSettings.setFcdEnabled(true);
    SKNavigationManager navigationManager = SKNavigationManager.getInstance();
    navigationManager.setMapView(mapView);
    navigationManager.setNavigationListener(MainActivity.this);
    navigationManager.startNavigation(navigationSettings);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found it on the demo app code.

```
mapView.getMapSettings().setMapDisplayMode(SKMapSettings.SKMapDisplayMode.MODE_3D);
```